# "name" [1]: -- missing -- error, when starting the server in hapi v17.4.0

Tags: email, hapi.js, reset-password

I am working on a hapi app and I want to implement forgot password logic by sending an email to the user. For that, I am using a plugin hapi-mail to send email using the SES service of AWS. I am getting an error:

```
"name" [1]: -- missing --
  },
  "options": {
    "template": {
      "engine": "handlebars",
      "path": "./templates/"
    },
    "email": {
      "engine": "ses",
      "options": {
        "region": "eu-west-1"
      },
      "defaultFrom": "abc@gmail.com"
    }
  }
}

[1] "name" is required
    at new AssertionError (internal/errors.js:469:11)
    at Object.exports.assert (/home/Utkarsh_Jaiswal/Documents/node-hapi-app/node-hapi-app/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:736:11)
    at Object.exports.apply (/home/Utkarsh_Jaiswal/Documents/node-hapi-app/node-hapi-app/node_modules/hapi/lib/config.js:22:10)
    at internals.Server.register (/home/Utkarsh_Jaiswal/Documents/node-hapi-app/node-hapi-app/node_modules/hapi/lib/server.js:392:31)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:228:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:576:3)
(node:8069) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8069) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that arenot handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Here is the code snippet to define options and register the plugin with the server:

```
const options = { 
    template: {
        engine: 'handlebars',
        path: './templates/' 
    },
    email: {
        engine: 'ses',
        options: { accessKeyId: access_key, secretAccessKey: secret_key, region: 'eu-west-1' },
        defaultFrom: 'abc@gmail.com'
    }
  };

await server.register([{
plugin: require('hapi-mail'),
options: options
}]);
```

How can this error be resolved? Also is there a better way to implement the idea. What should be the approach for handling this other than the one I am using?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you're trying to use is for an older version of Hapi. It requires version 15 going by the `package.json`.

Version 17 of Hapi, that you're using, [contains changes](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/3658) to how plugins are registered which are not backwards compatible with older version of Hapi.

You either need to find a different mail plugin that supports Hapi 17 or downgrade to use Hapi 15, however I wouldn't recommend the latter.

Comment: Can you provide any links for alternative plugins that can be used instead of hapi-mail??